# Collapsing menu content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a ul menu that collapses, but the content inside each menu li is going a little funny when it's width is toggled.

i tried .slideToggle but couldn't get it to operate to slide into the right button div.

It works well it is just a little clunky. I'm assuming there is a css rule that could fix my issue but I'm a little stuck

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zNX9N/2/)

this is the rule i am using which you can see in the jsfiddle.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-active').click(function() {
    $('#menu').animate({width: 'toggle'})
       });
});
```

i'm new to javascript so I'm sure there is a better method that I'm unaware of.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "a little funny"? Are you referring to the stuttering when the vertical scrollbar appears/disappears?

Comment: You don't need a `ready()` function for each event handler, you should write them in a single `ready()` function… and you don't need multiple handlers listening to same event for the same element.. you can write the code in a single handler..

Comment: @user3008011 it gets a little clunky and the menu text shifts under as i assume its running out of space.

Comment: section.menu add overflow hidden, that gets rid of the scroll bar appearing, also not everything has to be inside a separate doc ready http://jsfiddle.net/zNX9N/5/

Comment: @AndrewMatthew thanks that cleans up my javascript a lot haha, but i am still having the issue with the content inside each li. it sort of sticks a little when it is toggled. also i didn't not have the scroll bar issue but thank you must be a browser thing

Comment: also multiple id's in ame document is invalid. Before spamming jquery, css etc it'll be a good idea to take sometime to learn what they actually do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made modifications on your codes. There are redundant `$(document).ready();` and others. I've also modified your css code.

I just created an "illusion" in the modifications I've made and I hope this is what you're looking for.

Here's the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNX9N/7/).

Comment: @dunili just one question, how do i get the menu to start hidden on load?

Comment: @user2260099 hey, sorry for the late reply, you just add this code in the `$(document).ready();`: `$('.menu').css({right: -($('.menu').width())});` - this will do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Earlier i misunderstood your question. Here is the Updated answer with slide effect. But the thing is you need to use jquery ui also. check it out my fiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#menu-active').click(function() {
  $('#menu').toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
   });

  $('#close').click(function() {
$('#menu').toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
});
});
```

[**Working JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zNX9N/8/)

Comment: doesn't seem to effect anything the content still gets stacked over each other as the width shrinks

Comment: @user2260099, you can change `1000` to `500` or less to make it animate faster if you want. :)